# How to get the auto increment primary key in old mdb database?

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, ado.net, dao

I have to retrieve the Auto_Increment primary key (id) after inserting a new row in a mdb access database.
Having mdb file in the old Access 97 version too, I cannot use "SELECT @@Identity;", because it is not supported.

Besides, in a multi users environment I do not like the idea to use Max(ID).

Actually the only solution I have, it is to use the DAO as:

```
Dim db As Database          'Test Database
Dim rs As Recordset         'Test Table
...
rs.AddNew
id = rs!id
```

but I have to add a reference to the DAO COM DLL, while I would like to have a full managed .NET code.

Do you have any suggestion how to retrieve the Auto_Increment primary key (after inserting a new row) without using DAO or Max(ID)?

Here my code to add a new row:

```
    Using oConn As New OleDbConnection(m_ConnString)
        oConn.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlInsert, oConn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could use Max, if you do the insert and select in a transaction. It's a bit crap I know, but it is Access97...

Comment: Sorry, but I think you'll need to use the DAO reference unless you can update the MDB to a later Access format. Tony's comment is right - I'm not sure if I really trust Access transactions, but you could give it a go.

Comment: @Tony: ok for the transaction, but the Max produces overheads that I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @Ben: Upgrading the mdb file is also an option for me, but I fear to put the hands in a (well) working mdb file (very old and with a lot of data).

Comment: Probably a well founded fear. Access 97 to 2000 was a pretty rocky transition. Widely agreed that 97 was the best version ever. It's all been downhill from there.

Comment: Added ms-access to your tag. The guys that monitor that tag could have an answer

Comment: They rewrote a lot of the database/VB integration to accommodate the transition from access VB to the Office-wide VB and it's never worked as well since.
Still, they may have fixed some of the transition problems with the 2003 format. I'd definitely upgrade a throwaway copy and test extensively before upgrading the live files, but it might be worth it. 97 is getting pretty old now.
Honestly, is it a problem to have DAO or just a purist thing?

Comment: Do you have a date field by any chance? Was LastModified property available for recordsets in '97? If you are moving up, you may as well go all the way to 2010.

Comment: @Ben: I agree, 97-mdb are very robust and never tried to upgrade them. I think that DAO is just a purist thing (for me) and I am going to use it. I just wanted to aks here to see if any .NET alternative is still possible.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any other mandatory field in this table that has a unique index, you may query its value after your insertion with something like `DFirst("ID", "tablename", "myfield = givenvalue")`. If you're running in a transaction, use a recordset (perhaps the same as for the insertion) instead of DFirst.